# Neo4j raises java.lang.OutOfMemory exception when inserts large data

Tags: transactions, neo4j, out-of-memory

everyone

My programe raises java.lang.OutOfMemory exception when inserts large data,althrough,I had use d some tunning tips, as change java_opts and transaction batching commit.I heard that JVM will reduce memory usage as Neo4J commited its transaction.but it seems doesn't work.
And when it processed 7,000,000 rows Exception raised,any advice?

this is my Neo4j properties

```
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=20M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=20M
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=400M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1000M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=400M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=400M
```

this is my JVM OPTS

```
 java -jar -server -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC neodataio.jar $@
```

this is my code

```
public Node createNode(String type, String v) {
stype = type;
UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory(
    db, type) {
    @Override
    protected void initialize(Node created,
        Map<String, Object> properties) {
    created.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label(stype));
    created.setProperty("v", properties.get(stype));
    }

};
return factory.getOrCreate(type, v);
}

private void processLine(String line) {
line = stripeStr(line);
String[] fields = line.split("["+splitor+"]");
List<Node> row = new ArrayList<Node>();
Map<String,Boolean> unqi = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
for (String field : fields) {
    String[] kvs = field.split("["+kv+"]");
    if(kvs.length==2
        &&!unqi.containsKey(kvs[1])
        &&!stripeStr(kvs[1]).equals("")
        &&!stripeStr(kvs[1]).toLowerCase().equals("null")){
    Node n = createNode(stripeStr(kvs[0]), stripeStr(kvs[1]));
    row.add(n);
    unqi.put(kvs[1], true);
    }
}
if (row.size() > 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < row.size(); i++) {
    row.get(0).createRelationshipTo(row.get(i), Importer.connect);
    }
}
}

private void processBatch(ArrayList<String> batch){
Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
try {
    for(String line : batch) {        
        processLine(line);        
    }    
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.close();
}
}

private String stripeStr(String str){
return str.trim().replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "");
}

public void processFile(String filepth) throws IOException {
long begin = new Date().getTime();
File f = new File(filepth);
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedReader dr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi)); 
String line;
int i = 1;
ArrayList<String> batch = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line=dr.readLine())!=null){
    batch.add(line);
    if(i%batchsize == 0){
    processBatch(batch);
    batch = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println(i);
    }
    i++;
}
processBatch(batch);
System.out.println(i);
long end = new Date().getTime();
System.out.println("cost time:"+(end-begin));
}
```

Exception

```
 Exception in thread "GC-Monitor" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.MeasureDoNothing.run(MeasureDoNothing.java:84)
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:140)
    at com.bfd.finance.neo4j.dataio.Importer.processBatch(Importer.java:79)
    at com.bfd.finance.neo4j.dataio.Importer.processFile(Importer.java:98)
    at com.bfd.finance.neo4j.dataio.Importer.main(Importer.java:161)
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: commit threw exception
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:498)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:397)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:122)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:124)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:553)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:460)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:901)
    at java.util.HashMap.putForCreate(HashMap.java:554)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAllForCreate(HashMap.java:559)
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:298)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.applyCommit(WriteTransaction.java:817)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.doCommit(WriteTransaction.java:751)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:322)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commitWriteTx(XaResourceManager.java:530)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commit(XaResourceManager.java:446)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.commit(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:545)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the batch inserter - http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html. Also consider periodically committing your transaction, e.g. every 100 inserts.

Comment: I had studied at batch insert,but it can't provide the way of 'get or create'.And I had use batch committing in my code.

Comment: What is your batch-size? Could it be that you created an outer transaction? So that all the tx you create here are just nested tx?

Answer (score 1):

What we do is commit the transaction every 5000 nodes and that works perfectly. The obvious drawback is that you cannot rollback the first 5000 nodes when there is a problem with node 5001.

As for batchinserter. If you use your program to import 1-time data without needing the database to be available for other request, it can be used. For all other big import use cases, batchinserter will not help you.

Comment: Could you post your JVM opts and Neo4j properties?I guess there are some problems with mine

Comment: We are using the default settings for neo4j. For the JVM we had to add extra memory:  -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M